# Avoid slide react native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, navigator

I am stuck ... i try to avoid the fact to change route by using slide in my project. When a user is on my Main page he can choose to go to Config page and in this page he can found a button which call my main page BUT i can also swipe and i want to cancel this do you know how to do that ?

call to config page//

```
gotoConfig() {
 this.state.switch_auto = false;
 if (this.state.appState == "active")
  this.props.navigator.push({
    component: config,
    passProps: {
      id: '3',
      name: 'page_de_config',
    },
    nameForButton : 'config',
  })
}
```

and

```
     <Navigator style={{flex:1}}
      initialRoute={{name: 'Main', component: Main, index: 0}}

     renderScene={(route, navigator) =>    {
        if (route.component) {
        return React.createElement(route.component, 
       { ...this.props, ...route.passProps, navigator, route,gestures: {},} );
            }
          }}
          navigationBar={
            <Navigator.NavigationBar routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper} />
          } />
```

thanks a lot